# How to install TortoiseGit without admin rights?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I work on virtual machine with restricted rights. I **can** install any program that do not require admin rights during the installation process. But installing TortoiseGit requires the rights because it integrates with explorer. Is it possible to install TortoiseGit without admin rights? May be without explorer integration.

My system is Windows 7 x64, TortoiseGit version is 1.8.3.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not yet: [bug 726](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/726) is still opened.
This installation with reduced features has been done for mercurial ([portable TortoiseHg](http://portableapps.com/node/28151)), but not for TortoiseGit yet.

The only workaround, mentioned in [this comment](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/726#note_1774425) is to install it once (with elevated privileges), zip the installation directory, and use that archive on other machine.
Obviously the all menu integration in the Windows Explorer wouldn't be present.

That requires a [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable version though](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/solutions/windows/82-how-to-fix-the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-on-windows.html) (also [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473912/visual-studio-11-and-handling-msvcr110-dll)):

> If you run a application and got the error message

```
The program can’t start because MSVCR110.dll is missing from your computer.
```

> then **the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is missing on the current computer**.
>
> This error appears when you wish to run a software which require the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2012.
>   The redistributable can easily be downloaded on the Microsoft website as x86 or x64 edition.
>
> Depending on the software you wish to install you need to install either the 32 bit or the 64 bit version.
>   If you do not know which version you need to install, start to install the 32 bit version and if you still got the error install then the 64 bit version.
>   On a 32 bit OS you can install only the 32 bit redistributable.
>
> You need to install the correct Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. If the software you wish to run require the 2012 DLLs it will not start with the 2010 ones.
>
> You can install both versions on the same computer at the same time (if this is a 64bit OS).

---

[Mark Ch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5414907/mark-ch) adds in the comment:

> Once done, you can run it as:

```
c:\[full path]\TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log
```

> from your workspace folder using a command prompt or a shortcut.
>   This brings up the log window, from which it is possible to get to virtually every other function.

Comment: I have done that. But how run after extracting archive? If run TortoiseGitProc.exe it show popup and tell that it can not find MSVCR110.dll.

Comment: @Cherry that must be because the one making the comment about the archive solution must already have a Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable version on his/her computer. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10473912/6309 or http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/solutions/windows/82-how-to-fix-the-program-cant-start-because-msvcr110-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-error-on-windows.html

Comment: once done, you can run it as c:\\[full path]\TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log from your workspace folder using a command prompt or a shortcut. This brings up the log window, from which it is possible to get to virtually every other function

Comment: @MarkCh Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. See [Issue 726](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=726) on TortoiseGit homepage.

Answer (score 0):

It can be duplicate but need a more clear more searchable note to create a portable TortoiseGit. Hope it's helpful and saving time for someone.

1. Install TortoiseGit normally
2. **Create portable TortoiseGit by coping the installation directory** of TortoiseGit to other location.
3. Uninstall TortoiseGit

Run portable TortoiseGit

- Run command line: `TortoiseGitProc.exe /command:log /path:"[project directory]"`
- Write a vbs script to select directory or type path then pass into `TortoiseGitProc.exe`. I followed this.
- Add a custom context menu by adding into Windows registry